# How is a solution linked to source control?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, version-control

I am trying to setup a solution to use Git source control in Visual Studio. Its not working at all and I have n publish option. So all I want to do is break the current connection to team foundation service and start again.

But if i delete the solution file and all the .git repositories and then open the project and save the resulting solution, there is no Add Solution to control option.

Instead all the usual commit options are there so for whatever reason the project is still linked to the previous revision control setup even tho i deleted the solution file.

How do i start again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With git you don't use the 'add to source control' option. You simply add the TFS server as a remote for your git repo and then push to it using Visual Studio or the git tooling of your choice. You can use the command 'git remote -v' to check if git has TFS configured as a remote.

When you open the solution in VS it will detect that the solution file is located in a git repository and will enable all the git source control features.

If this was an existing project bound to TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) then you might need to unbind it first, and it might also be worth checking that Visual Studio is using the Microsoft Git provider (in Tools-Options-Source Control-Plugin Selection).